# Loading JSON cross-domain using an HTTPS url with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I'm trying to get some JSON data from an URL using the following AngularJS code:

```
'use strict';

/* Controllers */

var phonecatApp = angular.module('phonecatApp', []);

phonecatApp.controller('PhoneListCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
  $scope.test = "Not loaded";
  delete $http.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'];
  $http.get('https://live.mpare.net/users.json').success(function(data) {
    $scope.test = data;
  }).
  error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    // called asynchronously if an error occurs
    // or server returns response with an error status.
  });
  ;
});
```

However, the JSON file isn't loaded. If I try a different URL, namely http://ip.jsontest.com, it *does* work.

I've retrieved the header for the https website using curl:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Sat, 08 Nov 2014 10:53:04 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.29 (Amazon)
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.29
Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=epp00ffbe0nmtogpj8dcvnfvg2; path=/
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Length: 119
Connection: close
Content-Type: application/json
```

The header for the http website looks like this:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Sat, 08 Nov 2014 10:53:04 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.29 (Amazon)
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.29
Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=epp00ffbe0nmtogpj8dcvnfvg2; path=/
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Length: 119
Connection: close
Content-Type: application/json
```

How can I load the https JSON file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for cross domain you have to use CORS, check this article on CORS [here](http://aameer.github.io/articles/cross-origin-resource-sharing-cors/), you can use jsonp if you want but you cant do post call with that.Hope it helps

Answer (score -1):

What worked was the following:

replace `$http.get` with `$http.jsonp` and put `?callback=JSON_CALLBACK` at the end of the url. The following code worked for me:

```
'use strict';

/* Controllers */

var phonecatApp = angular.module('phonecatApp', []);

phonecatApp.controller('PhoneListCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
  $scope.test = "Not loaded";
  delete $http.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'];
  $http.jsonp('https://live.mpare.net/users.json?callback=JSON_CALLBACK').success(function(data) {
    $scope.test = data;
  }).
  error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    // called asynchronously if an error occurs
    // or server returns response with an error status.
  });
  ;
});
```